# Rinkeby offline

Tags: blockchain, ether, testnets, faucets, authentication

I’m newbie in using Rinkeby authenticated faucet. When I opened the site I discover that there is and indication saying OFFLINE. Is there anything that I’m not doing right. Please I need help.

Comment: FYI Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet running bc of the recent Ethereum Merge. All others including Rinkeby, Ropsten, and Kovan have been deprecated. If you need any free Goerli testETH, Alchemy has a pretty reliable faucet - https://goerlifaucet.com. 

I consistently get 0.1 ETH every day which is usually enough for all my basic testnet needs.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the testnet faucet undergoes maintenance or is overloaded with requests. You should try using Chainlink's Rinkeby faucet:

https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

Note: this faucet just worked for me. You can only request 0.1 testnet ETH, but its a good backup for when the main faucet goes down. The benefit of it is you can do multiple requests back to back.